# SolidSolver for blender?

Tags: mesh, geometry, 3d-printing, shrinkwrap, remesh

This is a question that is asked a lot, and the answers are generally of the "do 15 different things" that don't actually work. (the usual error being deletion of whatever internal vertices end up being selected breaks the surface manifold)

I'm hoping that with the rise of 3d printing, someone has come up with a smart, 1 click solution.

I have a 3d object that is manifold. it has a single continuous outer surface.

It also has an absolute heap of internal geometry, faces with the normals pointing in the wrong directions etc. thin faces, thick faces, generally an utter mess with 100k + things going on inside that i don't want or need.

As a thought experiment, a tool like 'shrink wrap' with infinitely stretchy shrink (so it creates a properly aligned, single surface  touching every part of my awful but manifold mess), would completely solve all my issues. Yet for some reason people appear to frown on the idea that i haven't started with clean models and built everything from scratch with great care and consideration for fixing internal geometry with every join and tell me to rebuild my models rather than considering how awesome a good tool would be.

So my question is, is there a plugin for blender that works like solidsolver, that will generate a proper, manifold, surface that is 1:1 with my manifold but internally messy mesh.

thanks!

Comment: "*Is there a plugin for blender that works like solidsolver,*" There isn't as far as I know, hence the recommendations for "*building everything from scratch with great care and consideration*". It is probably called **Solid**Solver because this is generally the job of solid based geometry engines commonly found in CAD software, not so much successful on mesh modelling.

Comment: If however you have an "*object that is manifold. it has a single continuous outer surface.*" why not just select that same surface and erase everything else?